# Is there any way to trigger DHCP via C code

Tags: c, linux, networking

To Set the static IP we have Linux Ioctls call through which we can set the IP, gateway, broadcast. 
Do we have similar ioctl calls for DHCP?

Comment: I'd say no, the DHCP client does the DHCP talking and uses `ioctl` to set the IP address, etc.

Comment: Your DHCP client *might* expose an API that allows talking to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Operation) is a protocol, not an "action". DHCP specifies "how" a host should enumerate ip.

If you want to trigger ip enumeration using DHCP protocol (I mean sending DHCPDISCOVER or DHCPREQUEST to the network and then acting on the response), there's no ioctl command for that. For using DHCP protocol and for ip enumeration and assignment respond user space applications called "dhcp clients", like [dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd) or [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd) or [dhclient](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient) or [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager).

`ioctl` performs a variety of actions on streams, usually `ioctl` is implemented as a call to the kernel. The kernel does not have an "dhcp client", ie. the clients are implemented user-side. The kernel does not takes responsibility for DHCP related actions. There is no ioctl calls for DHCP related actions. There is a [ioctl_list](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html) available to check out.

If you want to trigger DHCP enumeration using C, you need to identify the dhcp client your system uses and then notify it / force it to do the action you request. Or you can write your own dhcp client. On my system I use 
 NetworkManager. As I don't have the time to learn how to communicate with NetworkManager using DBUS and I have [nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) tool installed on my system, I can just call [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) from C to force DHCP lease renewal on my system: `system("nmcli con down id MY_WIFI_NAME; nmcli con up id MY_WIFI_NAME;");`.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your point, I am also using the system to trigger udhcpc client. But due to some Security reasons system call cannot be used directly in my project. That's why thinking on an alternative way. As per your explanation now I am clear what needs to be done, thanks.

Comment: the link to ioctl list is dead. better to quote important text